# Help with focus/blur semantics in jquery

Tags: jquery, focus, blur

```
...

  $(document).ready(function(){

        $('form').submit(function(){
                $('input#second').focus();
                return false;
        });

        $('#first').blur(function(){
                alert('blur');
        });
  });

...

  <form>
    <input id=first><br>
    <input id=second><br>
    <input type=submit>
  </form>

...
```

1. Load the page
2. Click on first input to give it focus
3. Hit Enter to submit the form

Then the following happens:

1. $('form').submit() is called and
2. It sets focus to the #second input and exits
3. #first looses focus, #second gets it, but...
4. $('#first').blur() **is not called**

Here is a [live demo](http://swapped.cc/tmp/jquery-blur-quirk.html).

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Which browser? Your markup isn't valid so that may be affecting things cross-browser.

Comment: FF 3.6 on Windows. Same in Chrome.

Comment: I'm experiencing it in Safari. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/JCUKr/) that uses a `setTimeout()` to move from first to second. The `blur()` doesn't fire when the `focus()` changes programmatically, but it does via mouse clicks.

Comment: @Alex - It works fine in Chrome here, even your test page

Comment: @patrick and @Nick, it seems to be a (*dare i say*) bug of jquery .. because [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/JCUKr/1/) using the javascript `focus()` works..

Comment: @Gaby - Yep you're right, the native `.focus()` triggers it. Must be a bug.

Comment: @Nick - Chrome (on Mac) fails for me in the OP's demo, and mine. Odd.

Comment: @Gaby - my thoughts exactly. Hence the 'bugs' tag :)

Comment: @Nick @patrick dw - fails for me under Chrome dev on linux too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this comment](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7311#comment:1) over at JQuert bugtracker, the work around the problem is to 
use

`$('input#second')[0].focus();`

instead of

`$('input#second').focus();`

Whether it is a bug is still to be decided by jq people in charge, but I would guess that it is because

1. the behaviour appears to be browser-specific
2. no reason why calling focus() on the array with one element should not be the same as calling it specifically for that element

Thanks, everyone. Night.

Answer (score 2):

Nick is right your HTML is really messed up. You have not ended you input tags or the br(s).  On top of that you should put your attribute values in your input tags in double quotes.

This works here is a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/dAdG8/) http://www.jsfiddle.net/dAdG8/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
         $('input#second').focus();
         return false;
    });

     $('#first').blur(function(){
         alert('blur');
     });

     // logging
     $('input').blur(function(){
         $('pre').append('blur, ' + this.id + '\n');
     });

     $('input').focus(function(){
         $('pre').append('focus, ' + this.id + '\n');
     });
});
</script>

<form>
     <input id="first" />
     <br />
     <input id="second" />
     <br />
     <input type="submit" />
 </form>
```

Comment: This isn't correct, it works fine in Chrome...the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Moreover, this is clearly not a mark-up issue, because adding onblur to #first works - specified onblur() code is executed. Just try adding onblur="alert('onblur');" to the first input tag.

Comment: @Alex I just ran it and its functioning as it should.  I see the alert(blur)

Comment: @John - well, and I don't :) FF 3.6.11 on Windows XP. This must be a JQ bug, I don't see any other explanation.

Comment: @Alex...acutally the issue I see is not that the blur is not called but the focus to the second input is not called

Comment: @John - The `.focus()` handler on the second input *is* called. In your demo, you left out the `<pre>` tag for logging, so you can't see the effect of the `.focus()`. Here's your demo with the `<pre>` tag in HTML. http://www.jsfiddle.net/dAdG8/1/

Comment: @Alex - I wouldn't submit a ticket with completely invalid markup like that, it's not a valid test case at all, invalid markup = unpredictable results. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://swapped.cc/tmp/jquery-blur-quirk.html&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0